# Text value of a hyperlink field in email template

Tags: email-template, merge-field, hyperlink, sales-process

I am having a hyperlink field in Opportunity object as follows:

- Label : **ObjectA Name**
- Value : **HYPERLINK('/'+ObjectA__c , ObjectA__r.Name)**

I want to use text value of hyperlink field in an email template.

Is there any way ?

NB: Now its coming as `<a href="/0015E00000Clv2M" target="_blank">ObjectA Name</a>`

Comment: why not use Account.Name in email template instead of hyperlink field?? Simplify

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I have modified the question. Actually, it's not account. It's a custom object. We don't have related object fields available in email template merge fields.